# Apache Nifi 2.x - org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Invalid SNI

Tags: java, jetty, apache-nifi, minify

i was trying to upgrade NiFi to 2 from 1.24. while starting Nifi, service started and port 8443 is listening.But i am getting error 400 on web page

From the web:

```
HTTP ERROR 400 Invalid SNI
URI:    /nifi
STATUS: 400
MESSAGE:    Invalid SNI
SERVLET:    -
CAUSED BY:  org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Invalid SNI


org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Invalid SNI
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer.customize(SecureRequestCustomizer.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer.customize(SecureRequestCustomizer.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.produce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection.produce(HTTP2Connection.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection.onFillable(HTTP2Connection.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection$FillableCallback.succeeded(HTTP2Connection.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.run(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

and from app.log

```
2023-11-30 09:56:46,456 WARN [NiFi Web Server-32] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel handleException /nifi org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Invalid SNI
2023-11-30 09:56:46,527 WARN [NiFi Web Server-36] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel handleException /favicon.ico org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Invalid SNI
```

Comment: "bad SNI" means that your client and your server do not agree on the hostname for that server.  Can you detail how you are accessing your server? and how your server is setup (pay attention to your TLS certificate details, do not use IP addresses or `localhost` or `localdomain` style host names, as those are unsupported by java's TLS implementation)

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Jetty 10, which is included with NiFi 2.0.0-M1, incorporates updates to the Server Name Indication processing during the TLS handshake. As a result of these changes, the default behavior does not support accessing NiFi using an IP address. Using a hostname or DNS name will avoid the SNI error and allow standard TLS negotiation to work.

My issue got fixed once i accessed nifi with FQDN

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I.e., make sure to set `nifi.web.https.host` to your FQDN `fqdn.example.com` and not an IP address in `conf/nifi.properties`:

`nifi.web.https.host=fqdn.example.com`

Comment: could you please share a detailed explanation?